# Can ngrams be generated in bash?

Tags: bash

I've found various implementations of ngrams in Python, Perl, etc., but I'd really like something in a bash script. I ran across the "Missing textutils" version, but that only lists the ngrams, it doesn't count them by frequency, which is fairly central to using ngrams -- or at least to my usage. I just want a basic list of results with their frequency, like this...

```
17 blue car
14 red car
5  and the
2  brown monkey
1  orange car
```

Anybody have something like that lying around that they could post? Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by 'ngram'?  A more complete example would be better than just sample output.

Comment: Sure. An "ngram" is any combination of words in a corpus (text, usually a plain text file). A bigram is two words ("blue car"), a trigram is three words ("a blue car"), and so on. "n" simply means the number of words is arbitrary, though in practice, it's rare to see more than five. Typically, the value in identifying ngrams is measuring their frequency in the text.

Comment: For more detail, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram . A great gui example is antconc, which I'm using currently, but I'd love to simply call a script. Here's the existing script I mentioned: http://www1.cuni.cz/~obo/textutils/ngrams

Comment: I found this: https://www.sketchengine.co.uk/documentation/wiki/SkE/NGrams . But I couldn't find other mentions of these tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a pure bash implementation.  You'll need to use a version of bash >= 4.2 with support for associative arrays.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

((n=${1:-0})) || exit 1

declare -A ngrams

while read -ra line; do
        for ((i = 0; i < ${#line[@]}; i++)); do
                ((ngrams[${line[@]:i:n}]++))
        done
done 

for i in "${!ngrams[@]}"; do
        printf '%d\t%s\n' "${ngrams[$i]}" "$i"
done
```

Save as `ngram` and use as `ngram 2 < file`.

Comment: Thanks! Any need of `chmod` on `ngram`?

Comment: code considers word followed by space as two different words and counted as bigram.

Comment: This does not work if the n-gram has a single quote in it.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, ngrams can be implemented in bash.

```
# Usage: ngrams N < FILE
ngrams () { 
  local N=$1
  local line
  set --
  while read line; do
    set -- $* $line
    while [[ -n ${*:$N} ]]; do
      echo ${*:1:$N}
      shift
    done
  done |
  sort | uniq -c
}

$ ngrams 2
Here is some text, and here is
some more text, and here is yet
some more text
  1 Here is
  2 and here
  2 here is
  2 is some
  1 is yet
  1 more text
  1 more text,
  2 some more
  1 some text,
  2 text, and
  1 yet some
```

Note: the above is a *function*, not a *script* (perhaps this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276476/functions-vs-scripts-unix-bash-programming) helps, or maybe there is another one which is better). Here's the script version:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: ngrams N < FILE
N=$1
set --
while read line; do
  set -- $* $line
  while [[ -n ${*:$N} ]]; do
    echo ${*:1:$N}
    shift
  done
done |
sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: Thanks very much for posting this, but I don't seem to be able to get it working. The example you give doesn't appear consistent with the usage instructions in the first line. I've tried it both ways, and nothing happens.

Comment: @user1889034: You probably put it in a file and tried to execute the file. That will do precisely nothing; it's a shell function, so it has to be called from the shell. I added the script version to the answer. The usage comment is correct; it reads from `stdin`. If you don't use `< FILE`, it will just read directly from `stdin` (the console itself, if you invoke it from a console, as I did in the example).

Comment: Please explain this one: ${*:$N} it is very hard to search for!  ty

Comment: @slashdottir: It's a ["substring" expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), which is really a subsequence expansion in this case, indicating a concatenation of positional parameters starting at `$N` (assuming `$N` is an integer). The use of `*` rather than `@` is undocumented, so I probably should change it (and it should have been quoted, in any event.) In other words, `[[ -d ${*:$N} ]]` is a test to see if there is some positional parameter whose index is at least `$N`. `${*:1:$N}` is the sequence of positional parameters from index 1 to `$N`.

Comment: In the script, `$N` is undefined.

Comment: @ChristianLindig: Thanks. Fixed.